# cl/gl interop : clCreateFromGLTexture2D with GLIntercept fails on AMD FUSION

Tags: opengl, opencl, gpu, amd-processor

I have a clgl interop executable which is making a call to `clCreateFromGLTexture2D`. It fails for that call...

```
clCreateFromGLTexture2D( 0x06691828, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 1, CL_INVALID_GL_OBJECT ) = 0x00000000
```

I am using [GLIntercept](http://code.google.com/p/glintercept/). here. So I am using Opengl32.dll generated by GLIntercept here...
Ok, it works on Nvidia GTX and runs standalone fine without intercept on AMD FUSION with AMD Radeon GPU. However, it fails when using the open source GLIntercept.

The clgl interop test code is posted there if you are interested in downloading and recreating the problem..

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?
Here are some statements from the my debug log... If it helps..

I created an open [issue/ticket on GLIntercept code website](http://code.google.com/p/glintercept/issues/detail?id=2) if you are interested in downloading the test sample clgl interop code which I am using for this...

```
glutInit(  ) = 
glutInitDisplayMode( 12 ) 
glutInitWindowSize( 320, 258 ) 
wglChoosePixelFormat( 38010929, 001EF950 PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR {  nSize 28 nVersion 1 dwFlags 25  PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER  PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW  PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL  iPixelType PFD_TYPE_RGBA cColorBits   cRedBits  cRedShift   cGreenBits  cGreenShift   cBlueBits  cBlueShift   cAlphaBits   cAlphaShift   cAccumBits   cAccumRedBits   cAccumGreenBits   cAccumBlueBits   cAccumAlphaBits   cDepthBits   cStencilBits   } 28 ) = 0x2
wglGetCurrentContext(  ) = 0x00000000
wglGetCurrentDC(  ) = 0x00000000
glutCreateWindow( OpenGL-CL interraction! ) = 0x1
glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0 ) 
glEnable( b71 ) 
glEnable( de1 ) 
glGenTextures( 1, 0125B194 { 1}  ) 
glBindTexture( de1, 1 ) 
glTexEnvi( 2300, 2200, 1e01 ) 
glTexParameteri( de1, 2801, 2600 ) 
glTexParameteri( de1, 2800, 2600 ) 
glTexImage2D( de1, 0, 8058, 100, 100, 0, 1908, 1401, 00C2E858 ) 
glBindTexture( de1, 0 ) 
clGetPlatformIDs( 0, NULL, 1 ) = CL_SUCCESS
clGetPlatformIDs( 1, 05744514, NULL ) = CL_SUCCESS
clGetDeviceIDs( 05744514, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, 04516F40 , NULL ) = CL_SUCCESS
clGetDeviceInfo( 0x04516F40, CL_DEVICE_NAME, 400, BeaverCreek, NULL ) = CL_SUCCESS
clGetDeviceInfo( 0x04516F40, CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS, 400, cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_ext_atomic_counters_32 cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd_vec3 cl_amd_printf cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_popcnt cl_khr_d3d10_sharing , NULL ) = CL_SUCCESS
wglGetCurrentContext(  ) = 0x00020000
wglGetCurrentDC(  ) = 0x38010929
wglGetCurrentContext(  ) = 0x00020000
clCreateContext( 8200  0x20000  8203  0x38010929  4228  0x5744514, 1, 04516F40 , NULL, NULL, CL_SUCCESS ) = 0x06A30828
clCreateCommandQueue( 0x06A30828, 0x04516F40, 0, CL_SUCCESS ) = 0x06A69900
clCreateProgramWithSource( 0x06A30828, 1, C:\Users\inteltc\Documents\clgl_latest\Debug\clgl_1.program, CL_SUCCESS ) = 0x06A6B9F8
clBuildProgram( 0x06A6B9F8, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL ) = CL_SUCCESS
clCreateKernel( 0x06A6B9F8, kernel1, CL_SUCCESS ) = 0x045266E0
clCreateFromGLTexture2D( 0x06A30828, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, GL_TEXTURE_2D, , 0, 1, CL_INVALID_GL_OBJECT ) = 0x00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you called glTexImage2D for your texture object, and that basically leaves the texture width, height and mipmaps undefined, so it's pretty obvious why it fails.

Comment: Actually it was getting called i have update the question posting with that call. That call information was not getting recorded. Anyways i have updated the question with that information..